# Xcode 12 print command doesn't show class fields

Tags: swift, xcode

I recently moved to a new MacBookPro. On the new machine and Xcode 12 the print command is working differently than it did before. I'm a little baffled what has changed. The new Xcode install is on MacOSX 10.15.7 and I'm running Xcode 12.4. I've made sure I have the right options in the console selected, there is no filter applied on left and the right side has "All Output" selected.

What I get in the console is "trans: apitest.Transaction" which is the name of the project and name of the class. My questions are these: Why is Xcode suddenly printing the name of the project? Also why doesn't it show any of the properties of the class? Is there a way to enumerate thru all the properties of the class instance without doing it manually? Thanks for your patience and help.

This is my class

```
import Foundation

final class Transaction: Codable {
        
    var id: Int?
    var date: Date
    var amount: Int
    var planeID: Int
    var userID: UUID
    var month: Int
    var year: Int

    init(date: Date, amount: Int, planeID: Int, userID: UUID, month: Int, year: Int) {
        self.date = date
        self.amount = amount
        self.planeID = planeID
        self.userID = userID
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
    }
}
```

And with a button in my app I'm trying to print the object

```
                let trans = Transaction(date: now, amount: 5, planeID: 5, userID: id, month: month, year: year)
        
        print("trans: \(trans)")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make it a struct instead of a class, you'll get that behavior for free. But, perhaps there are reasons it *has* to be a class. In that event, you can use reflection to print the keys without having to do it manually:

```
final class Transaction: Codable, ReflectedStringConvertible {
        
    var id: Int?
    var date: Date
    var amount: Int
    var planeID: Int
    var userID: UUID
    var month: Int
    var year: Int

    init(date: Date, amount: Int, planeID: Int, userID: UUID, month: Int, year: Int) {
        self.date = date
        self.amount = amount
        self.planeID = planeID
        self.userID = userID
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
    }
}

public protocol ReflectedStringConvertible : CustomStringConvertible { }

extension ReflectedStringConvertible {
  public var description: String {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
    
    var str = "\(mirror.subjectType)("
    var first = true
    for (label, value) in mirror.children {
      if let label = label {
        if first {
          first = false
        } else {
          str += ", "
        }
        str += label
        str += ": "
        str += "\(value)"
      }
    }
    str += ")"
    
    return str
  }
}
```

Idea taken from: https://medium.com/swift-programming/struct-style-printing-of-classes-in-swift-7ee34f1c975a

Comment: Thank you. But why is it now printing out the name of the project?

Comment: The default behavior for a class being printed is the package that it's part of (which happens to be the name of the project in this case) and then the class name itself. This would mean that if `Transaction` also appeared in another package, there wouldn't be namespace confusion.

Comment: If you're using LLDB during a debug session, you can. use the `p` command instead of `po` to print the properties of a class instance without having to implement `CustomStringConvertible`.